# Visual Studio 2015 and Microsoft Azure syncing files, Server/Local

Tags: node.js, visual-studio, azure

So, iam just starting to use Microsoft Azure with Visual Studio but i have some trubble to connect "100%" to my Azure storage.

With my FTP IDE (Jetbrains Webstorm) iam able to download all server side files to my local, using a simple Web Host storage service. With VS i only seems to get the "necessary" files to start my app on my local drive.

Comparing these two Explorers in VS, shows whats missing locally from the server side.

[**Server Explorer** (My NodeJS Project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6kaE.png)

[**Solution Explorer** (My NodeJS Project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0TlIC.png)

So i think my real question is based on the fact that i want FULL control of my server files. When i publish my project in VS, do i only get the "necessary" files, and all other management (move, delete, add, etc.) is done thru the server console?
And why is not all files synced between the server and the Local? Has i missed something in my deployment mind of not "thinking Azure"?

*OBS! Iam coming from a webbhost development with more then 5 years of experience in JS, HTTP and CSS.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure several sync mechanism to sync your local files and server files like building on a Git repo, or the files on local will not automatically sync the files on server by it self. You can refer to https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-publish-source-control/ for more information about using GIT in Azure App Service.

And for remote file operations, you can leverage Visual Studio Online, which is an online editor enable you to manage and develop your application on Azure App Service:

1. login Azure mange portal, enabled **EDIT IN VISUAL STUDIO ONLINE** under CONFIGURE tab
   [image]
2. click the edit in VSO under the DASHBOARD of your manage portal site
   [image]
3. then you can manage your files on server, even run console commands:
   [image]