# "Hello-World" node.js/express working locally, but not on Azure Web App

Tags: node.js, azure, express, azure-web-app-service

I have the following node.js/express file *index.js*.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
app.listen(port);
console.log("Server running at http://localhost:%d", port);
```

When I run the server locally and access *http://localhost:1337/* on my browser, I get "Hello World!" as expected.
I deployed the index.js on my Azure Web App but when I try to access it, I get a "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT".

What am I doing wrong?

I have already installed express on Azure.

Comment: What is your Azure Web App OS?

Comment: OS version: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0 (64 bit)

Comment: Did you include a web.config file in your project?

Comment: Yes, I used the web.config, package.json and process.json from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world/archive/master.zip.

Comment: What port are you using in Azure? Are you trying to query via port 1337? If so, that won't work.

Comment: I'm trying to access via http://<mysite>.azurewebsites.net/ (without port).

Comment: @G.Werner Hi,any progress with my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem,  have you tried deploying to a Linux App Service plan, this should work like a Charm, however, if you are using windows plan ensure you have added the web.config file check [this out](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/nodejs-docs-hello-world) hope it helps. For others facing similar issues, please ensure that you have port being called from process.env.PORT || XXX as the cloud hates hardcoded port values

Comment: Cheers @Samuel, this was the solution for me!

Answer (score 2):

G.Werner, firstly,you could enable debugging for error details, please follow the steps:

1) Create file iisnode.yml in your root folder (D:\home\site\wwwroot) if not exists.

2) Add the following lines to it.

```
loggingEnabled: true

logDirectory: iisnode
```

After that done, you can find logs in `D:\home\site\wwwroot\iisnode`.

Please refer to my working steps.

***app.js***

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);

console.log("+++++++++++++++"+ app.get('port'));

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;

app.listen(app.get('port'), function(){
          console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
          });
```

***web.config***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
     This configuration file is required if iisnode is used to run node processes behind
     IIS or IIS Express.  For more information, visit:

     https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config
-->

<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Visit http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2013/11/14/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites.aspx for more information on WebSocket support -->
    <webSocket enabled="false" />
    <handlers>
      <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
      <add name="iisnode" path="app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
    </handlers>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
        <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="^app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
        </rule>

        <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
        <rule name="StaticContent">
          <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
        </rule>

        <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
        <rule name="DynamicContent">
          <conditions>
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="app.js"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

    <!-- 'bin' directory has no special meaning in node.js and apps can be placed in it -->
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <hiddenSegments>
          <remove segment="bin"/>
        </hiddenSegments>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>

    <!-- Make sure error responses are left untouched -->
    <httpErrors existingResponse="PassThrough" />

    <!--
      You can control how Node is hosted within IIS using the following options:
        * watchedFiles: semi-colon separated list of files that will be watched for changes to restart the server
        * node_env: will be propagated to node as NODE_ENV environment variable
        * debuggingEnabled - controls whether the built-in debugger is enabled

      See https://github.com/tjanczuk/iisnode/blob/master/src/samples/configuration/web.config for a full list of options
    -->
    <iisnode watchedFiles="web.config;*.js"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

***routes/index.js***

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
});

module.exports = router;
```

***Access Result:***

[image]

More details ,please refer to this case: [Running Node.js on Azure Web App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35879626/running-node-js-on-azure-web-app).

In addition, you could also take a shot on the express template called "Basic Azure Node.js Express 4 App" in the Visual Studio 2017 Tool.

Any concern, please let me know.

Comment: I followed this to the tee. I still get 'No webpage was found for the web address'